# Как сделать всплывающие окна?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет!

Учусь разработке Android0приложения. Делаю вспылвающие окна.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Нажата кнопка ОК", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Выходит вот такая ошибка:

**The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, 
 String, int)**

В чем может быть проблема. Клик по кнопке реализую через интерфейс:

```
OnClickListener oCickBtnOk = new OnClickListener()
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Собственно, что написано, то и происходит. this у Вас View.OnClickListener. Замените на Activity.this

Comment: Вообще-то я очень советую Вам изучить просто Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты, наверное, `Toast.makeText(this, "Нажата кнопка ОК", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` написал в анонимном классе? Попробуй реализовать интерйфейс с помощью активити, как здесь:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
```

Либо пропиши MainActivity.this вместо this.

Comment: Мужик, ты красавчик! Спас меня от бессоной ночи! СПАСИБО!

Comment: ну так вставь вместо MainActivity название своей активити. А лучше выложи полный  в шапку темы свой полный код - как я отгадаю-то.